# Calling getListView().setChoiceMode() in ListFragment results in IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am an Android programming newbie trying to move a working app from Activities to Fragments.

In the ScanningFragment (which should show a list of nearby Bluetooth devices) I have put the following code:

```
public class ScanningFragment extends ListFragment {
    private ScanningListener mListener;

    static class Beacon {
        public String address;
        public int rssi;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image1;
        public CheckedTextView text1;
    }

    private ArrayList<Beacon> mBeacons = new ArrayList<Beacon>();
    private ArrayAdapter<Beacon> mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_scanning, container, false);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Beacon>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.rowlayout, 
                R.id.text1, 
                mBeacons) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.image1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
                    holder.text1 = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                Beacon beacon = (Beacon) getItem(position);
                holder.text1.setText(beacon.address);
                // TODO pass selected address here
                holder.text1.setChecked(beacon.address.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonConstants.ADDRESS_DEFAULT));
                int res = CommonConstants.rssi2res(beacon.rssi);
                holder.image1.setImageResource(res);                
                return convertView;
            }
        };     

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); // Exception!
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }
```

Unfortunately the line

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

bombs out with an IllegalStateException (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk7qJ.png)):

[image: screenshot]

And here is the trace (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9DK6.png), sorry I don't know how to copy text from Eclipse Debug window):

[image: trace]

Does anybody please know, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move that line to `onViewCreated()` instead of `onCreateView()`. In `onCreateView()` your `ListView` has not yet been created, so it will throw an `IllegalStateException` when you try to retrieve it.

Also, ensure that `activity_scanning.xml` contains a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

Comment: Thanks +1, this makes sense. Should I move just 1 line or everything following the "inflate" call?

Comment: Probably only need to move the one, but typically I do all view initialization in onViewCreated and do just the inflation in onCreateView.